# What version of Delphi were build configurations implemented?

Tags: delphi, conditional-compilation, buildconfiguration

I'm working on a project which includes conditionals to control what to compile for different versions of Delphi. I am only familiar with versions 7, 2010, and XE2. At least in Delphi 2010, there's the ability to create multiple Build Configurations on a project, each of which allows you to compile your application differently based on the currently selected configuration. I just need to know what version of Delphi were these build configurations introduced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are new since Delphi 2007. It says so in the [What's New in Delphi 2007](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/36608). No mentions of it in the What's New of [Delphi 2006](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33411).